# How can I get access to a value after looping a asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I am trying to run throw a loop of asynchronous function and calculate the sum of all elements, where I can access the final `sum`.

```
it("Select.all practice", function(){
    element.all(by.css('.items li')).then(function(items) {
        var len = items.length;
        var sum = "";
        for(var counter = 0; counter<len;counter++){
            items[counter].getText().then(function(item){
                sum += item;
                console.log(sum);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty useful [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) function, which fits the use case perfectly:

```
element.all(by.css('.items li')).reduce(function(acc, elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return acc + parseInt(text);
    });
}, 0).then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Holy! I should start looking for a job on Protractor. I had no idea that `reduce` function existed!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are dealing with String while trying to do the addition. Try the following

```
it("Select.all practice", function(){
    element.all(by.css('.items li')).then(function(items) {
        var len = items.length;
        var sum = 0;
        for(var counter = 0; counter<len;counter++){
            items[counter].getText().then(function(item){
                sum += parseInt(item);
                console.log(sum);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, where can I access the sum value out side the loop? where to add then for add test after calculate the sum

Comment: @user1684140 please see the alternative approach using `reduce()`.

Comment: The main issue for the OP is with the *asynchronicity* of the operation, which this answer does **nothing** to solve.